Intellisense not working even c/c++ extension already downloaded
I'm trying to use C/C++ on vscode. I've already followed the step on here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw, but the intellisense keep not working.
I've already set up the path and any else. The code works fine, but the intellisense not working.
anyone know why?




Check includePath Setting: Make sure that the "includePath" setting in your c_cpp_properties.json file includes the paths to the header files you're using in your project. This is necessary for IntelliSense to work correctly.

Verify IntelliSense is Enabled: Go to File > Preferences > Settings (or press Ctrl+,), then search for "intellisense". Make sure that "C_Cpp: IntelliSense Engine" is set to "Default".

Yooooo, i've been trying to solve this problem for 1 streak week, and i just need to set that to "default"? Hahahahahaa, thank you so much.

Verify IntelliSense is Enabled: Go to File > Preferences > Settings (or press Ctrl+), then search for "intellisense". Make sure that "C_Cpp: IntelliSense Engine" is set to "Default".
